# Adding active class to dynamic Twitter Bootstrap carousel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Boostrap 2.x slider to display a series of testimonials on a webpage which I retrieve from a database.

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide">

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Testimonials)
        {
            <div class="item" style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden">
                <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                @item.Quote
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

For the slider to work, the first item needs to be set to 'active', otherwise the first item shown is blank. How do I add the 'active' class to the first item in MVC?

So the first item should display as

```
<div class="item active" style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden">
```

instead of

```
<div class="item" style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden">
```

In my script file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#testimonials').carousel({
    interval: 6000
});

$('#testimonials').carousel('cycle');
}
```

(there are 2 sliders on this page)

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check for the first item in the loop:

```
<div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @{
             var i = 0;
             foreach (var item in Model.Testimonials)
             {
                 var itemClass = i++ == 0 ? "item active" : "item";
                 <div class="@itemClass" style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden">
                     <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                     @item.Quote
                 </div>
             }
         }
    </div>
</div>
```

or replace `foreach` with `for` loop if your `Model.Testimonials` property is a type of `IList<T>` or any collection, which items can be individually accessed by index:

```
<div id="testimonials" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Testimonials.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = Model.Testimonials[i];
            var itemClass = i == 0 ? "item active" : "item";
            <div class="@itemClass" style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden">
                <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                @item.Quote
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to do this with JavaScript, so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel-inner .item:first').addClass('active');

    $('#testimonials').carousel({
        interval: 6000
    });

    $('#testimonials').carousel('cycle');
}
```

Also I would suggest you to move the `style="max-height:70px; overflow:hidden"` line to css class:

```
.carousel-inner .item {
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: "hidden";
}
```